# How can I leverage machine learning in my Business Intelligence/Data warehouse? Request

Tags: machine-learning, ai

I work in a Datawarehousing environment where we host a rich collections of data from different systems and have probably the most holistic view of the dataset across our organization. Some of them are our Marketing, Revenue, sales, opportunity, Employee, traffic etc. We are basically an internet company providing state-of-the-art technology to the industry. I am more interested in my contribution to the company by leveraging my knowledge and access to the data

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in the DS.SE.